# Liferay CE 6.2: How to Select Rows in Search Container in JSP File

Tags: jsp, liferay, portlet

I'm very new to liferay development, but I've made steady progress up to now. However, I've hit a roadblock.

I've created a portlet that has a configuration page following the liferay tutorials. In my configuration.jsp file, I retrieve some location records from a database, then display the location name from those records in a SearchContainer. I also have a second column which contains a checkbox for selection of that row, i.e. if the box is checked, that row is selected.

I'd like to get all the location IDs of all selected rows and store them as a portletPreference value, so the IDs can then be used to view certain data in view mode. I've read elsewhere that storing the IDs as a comma-separated string into a hidden input tag could be a way forward, but I can't get this to work. How do I use the hidden input to collate all the selected IDs?

Relevant parts from configuration.jsp:

```
<aui:form action="<%= configurationURL %>" method="post" name="fm">

<liferay-ui:search-container delta="20" emptyResultsMessage="No locations available!">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results
        results="<%= LocationAccessDescriptionsLocalServiceUtil.findByCustomerID(1)%>"
    />

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row
        className="com.database.model.LocationAccessDescriptions"
        keyProperty="locationID"
        modelVar="location"
    >
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
            name="name"
            value="<%= location.getLocationName()%>"
        />

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="select">
            <aui:input type="checkbox" name="loc_sel" class="loc_sel" value="<%=location.getLocationID() %>" />        
        </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>

    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator />

</liferay-ui:search-container>

<aui:button-row>
   <aui:button type="submit" />
</aui:button-row>
</aui:form>
```

I think it's something fundamental I'm missing, so please type slowly in response!

Edit 1: I've plodded onwards and got a little further. Thanks to the first comment below, I've managed to access the 'rowIds' value in my impl class, but I can't seem to access them in view mode.

As an alternative, I tried storing the selected IDs into a hidden input on submitting the form, but because I've used the preferences notation for the input name, this fails to compile. i.e. if I change 'preferences--selectedIDs--' to 'selectedIDs' it works, but is not stored as a portlet preference. That's not what I want. Has anybody done this kind of selection using a configuraiton.jsp file?

```
<!-- MAIN FORM -->
<aui:form action="<%= configurationURL %>" method="post" name="fm">

    <!-- HIDDEN INPUTS -->
    <aui:input name="<%= Constants.CMD %>" type="hidden" value="<%= Constants.UPDATE %>" />
    <aui:input name="preferences--selectedIDs--" type="hidden" />

    <!-- MAIN SEARCH CONTAINER -->
    <liferay-ui:search-container delta="20" emptyResultsMessage="No locations available!" rowChecker="<%= new RowChecker(renderResponse) %>">

    <liferay-ui:search-container-results
        results="<%= LocationAccessDescriptionsLocalServiceUtil.findByCustomerID(1)%>"
        total="<%= LocationAccessDescriptionsLocalServiceUtil.findByCustomerID(1).size()%>"
    />

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row
        className="com.database.model.LocationAccessDescriptions"
        keyProperty="locationID"
        modelVar="location"
    >

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
            name="ID"
            value="<%= String.valueOf(location.getLocationID())%>"
        />

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
            name="name"
            value="<%= location.getLocationName()%>"
        />

    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator />

    </liferay-ui:search-container>

    <aui:button-row>
       <aui:button
            value="SubmitForm"
            onClick='<%= renderResponse.getNamespace() + "SubmitForm();" %>' />
    </aui:button-row>

</aui:form>

<!-- AUXILIARY SCRIPTS -->
<aui:script>
Liferay.provide(
    window,
    '<std-portlet:namespace />SubmitForm',
    function()
    {
         var checkBoxValue = Liferay.Util.listCheckedExcept(document.<std-portlet:namespace />fm, "<std-portlet:namespace />allRowIds");
         document.<std-portlet:namespace />fm.<std-portlet:namespace />preferences--selectedIDs--.value=checkBoxValue;
         alert("Prefs Value: " + document.<std-portlet:namespace />fm.<std-portlet:namespace />preferences--selectedIDs--.value);
         submitForm(document.<std-portlet:namespace />fm, "<%=configurationURL%>");
    },
    ['liferay-util-list-fields']
);
</aui:script>
```

Comment: Liferay [search containers](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/dao/search/SearchContainer.html) have a built in row selection component ([RowChecker](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/dao/search/RowChecker.html)) that will group selected rows within a String[] parameter accessible, by the key `'rowIds'`, upon submittal of the form. One thing to consider is that the row selections do not persist through pagination navigation. If preference assignment can be on form submission, then I would go with the RowChecker.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you recommend a decent tutorial that walks through this? I've found a couple, but they're not really helping.

Comment: I can't recall any tutorials that I've used for it. If I can't find a tutorial on something I'll usually browse [the liferay source](https://github.com/liferay) on github and search for any usages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RowChecker of the Liferay SearchContainer:

Row Checker:
If you want to select multiple rows then you can go with row checker

I am posting the running code in Liferay DXP,

```
<aui:form name="show_fm">

<liferay-ui:search-container rowChecker="<%=new RowChecker(renderResponse) %>"  delta='10' deltaConfigurable="true" total="<%=fooLocalService.getFoosCount() %>" totalVar="countVar" emptyResultsMessage="empty-results" compactEmptyResultsMessage="true">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results results="<%=fooLocalService.getFoos(searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd()) %>"  />
    <liferay-ui:search-container-row
        className="com.example.sample.model.Foo"  escapedModel="<%= true %>" rowVar="curRow"
        keyProperty="fooId" modelVar="foo">

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="name"
            property="field1" />
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="age"
            property="field3" />
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="messasge"
            property="field5" />
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp name="action"
            path="/foo_action.jsp" align="right" />
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
    <liferay-ui:search-iterator markupView="lexicon" />
</liferay-ui:search-container>

<aui:button-row>
    <aui:button value="delete" onClick='<%= renderResponse.getNamespace() + "showSelectedFoos();"  %>' />
</aui:button-row>

</aui:form>

<aui:script>
Liferay.provide(
        window,
        '<portlet:namespace />showSelectedFoos',
         function() {
                    var cmd = 
                           Liferay.Util.listCheckedExcept(
                               document.<portlet:namespace />show_fm,   "<portlet:namespace />allRowIds"); 
                    if(cmd==""||cmd==null){
                         alert("Please select atleast one foo to delete");
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete Foos? ")) {

                        var actionURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createActionURL();
                        actionURL.setWindowState("<%=LiferayWindowState.NORMAL.toString() %>");
                        actionURL.setPortletMode("<%=LiferayPortletMode.VIEW %>");
                        actionURL.setParameter("selectedRows",cmd);
                        actionURL.setParameter("javax.portlet.action","deleteMultiple");
                        actionURL.setPortletId("<%=themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay().getId() %>");

                        submitForm(document.<portlet:namespace />show_fm, actionURL);

                }

          },
          ['liferay-util-list-fields', 'liferay-portlet-url']
);

</aui:script>
```

You can write the method in Portlet Controller:

```
public void deleteMultiple(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {
        String fooIds = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "selectedRows");
        System.out.println(fooIds);
        sendRedirect(actionRequest, actionResponse);
    }
```

This above code submitting the form with the selected rows to the Portlet method and fetch the selected row's entry id with comman seprated values. So now you can do the String operation and split the values and fetch the individual Ids and based on you can do your operations.

Comment: It just gives a sample example, it depends upon you how you are going to call